# Create bins dynamically that should contain approx. 1% of total NOBS after max bin range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bin

I have pandas DataFrame of numeric columns. This data does not contain any zeros(0).

I have defined a function that creates integer bins as follows

```
1. First bin label e.g. -20 for values <-10000000 or 
-1 for all negative values
2. Min. bin range (e.g. -10000000), Bin width (e.g. 500000) up to max. bin range (e.g. 5000000)
3. After the threshold (e.g. 20000000), it will dynamically size bins to contain 1% of the total count or NOBS (No. of Observations) 
    i.e. if NOBS is going below 1% of total NOBS then it will dynamically adjust the bin width such that it will be approx 1% of total NOBS.
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Reproducible example
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
a = rng.integers(-1687500000, 0, 5000)
b = rng.integers(0, 20000000, 25000)
c = rng.integers(20000000, 56956420100000, 4149)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': np.concatenate([a, b, c])})

def dynamic_binning(df_, col_, first_bin, first_bin_label, bin_width, threshold):

    # Create bins
    m = df_[col_] > threshold
    q = np.linspace(0, 1, 100 * sum(m) // len(df_))

    bins = [-np.inf] + np.arange(first_bin, threshold+1, bin_width).tolist()
    bins += df_.loc[m, col_].quantile(q).tolist()[1:]
    
    df_bins_ = (pd.cut(df_[col_].dropna(), bins, labels=False, right=False)
                  .value_counts().rename('NOBS'))

    # Fix missing bins
    idx = pd.RangeIndex(df_bins_.index.min(), df_bins_.index.max(), name='Bins')

    df_bins_ = (df_bins_.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
                        .assign(Percentage=lambda x: x['NOBS'] / len(df_) * 108,
                                Bins=lambda x: x['Bins'].astype(int) + first_bin_label))

    return df_bins_
```

Calling the function

```
dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', -10000000, -20, 500000, 5000000)
```

Output:

```
Bins    NOBS    Percentage
-20     4969    15.715013616796977
-19     2       0.006325221822015286
-18     1       0.003162610911007643
-17     2       0.006325221822015286
-16     2       0.006325221822015286
-15     1       0.003162610911007643
-14     0       0.0
-13     3       0.009487832733022929
-12     0       0.0
-11     2       0.006325221822015286
-10     2       0.006325221822015286
-9      0       0.0
-8      3       0.009487832733022929
-7      1       0.003162610911007643
-6      1       0.003162610911007643
-5      1       0.003162610911007643
-4      3       0.009487832733022929
-3      3       0.009487832733022929
-2      2       0.006325221822015286
-1      1       0.003162610911007643
0       1       0.003162610911007643
1       636     2.011420539400861
2       638     2.0177457612228764
3       604     1.9102169902486164
4       565     1.7868751647193184
5       647     2.046209259421945
6       640     2.0240709830448917
7       627     1.982957041201792
8       614     1.9418430993586928
9       665     2.1031362558200826
10      631     1.9956074848458227
11      609     1.9260300448036545
12      637     2.0145831503118687
13      627     1.982957041201792
14      661     2.0904858121760523
15      599     1.8944039356935782
16      602     1.903891768426601
17      647     2.046209259421945
18      642     2.030396204866907
19      604     1.9102169902486164
20      570     1.8026882192743565
21      355     1.1227268734077134
22      355     1.1227268734077134
23      355     1.1227268734077134
24      355     1.1227268734077134
25      355     1.1227268734077134
26      355     1.1227268734077134
27      355     1.1227268734077134
28      355     1.1227268734077134
29      355     1.1227268734077134
30      355     1.1227268734077134
31      355     1.1227268734077134
32      355     1.1227268734077134
33      355     1.1227268734077134
34      355     1.1227268734077134
35      355     1.1227268734077134
36      355     1.1227268734077134
37      355     1.1227268734077134
38      355     1.1227268734077134
39      355     1.1227268734077134
40      355     1.1227268734077134
41      355     1.1227268734077134
42      355     1.1227268734077134
43      355     1.1227268734077134
44      354     1.1195642624967057
45      355     1.1227268734077134
46      355     1.1227268734077134
47      355     1.1227268734077134
48      355     1.1227268734077134
49      355     1.1227268734077134
50      355     1.1227268734077134
51      355     1.1227268734077134
52      355     1.1227268734077134
53      355     1.1227268734077134
54      355     1.1227268734077134
55      355     1.1227268734077134
56      355     1.1227268734077134
57      355     1.1227268734077134
58      355     1.1227268734077134
59      355     1.1227268734077134
60      355     1.1227268734077134
61      355     1.1227268734077134
62      355     1.1227268734077134
63      355     1.1227268734077134
64      355     1.1227268734077134
65      355     1.1227268734077134
66      355     1.1227268734077134
```

However, for `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col3', 0, -1, 0.1, 3)` it is throwing an error `ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.` After debugging the code I found that there are a few values in list variable `bins` which are not in ascending order. `pd.cut()` expects bins should be in increasing order.

Bins of `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col3', 0, -1, 0.1, 3)` are

```
[-inf, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.300000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.600000001, 0.70000000001, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.200000000002, 1.3, 1.40000000001, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7000000002, 1.8, 1.9000000000000001, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.300000003, 2.400000004, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8000000000000003, 2.9000000000000004, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3000000000000003, 3.4000000000000004, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8000000000000003, 3.9000000000000004, 3.217874, 3.44, 3.684588, 3.96, 4.3, 4.73040825, 5.246687, 5.804751, 6.589519, 7.714112, 9.03, 11.370693, 14.962406, 21.879876, 43.65881375, 243441.0]
```

In the above list `...... , 3.6, 3.7, 3.8000000000000003, 3.9000000000000004, 3.217874, 3.44, 3.684588, 3.96, 4.3, .....` there is a drop in bins when we merge the output of

```
[-np.inf] + np.arange(first_bin, threshold+1, bin_width).tolist()
```

with

```
df_.loc[m, col_].quantile(q).tolist()[1:]
```

Stats of `'Col3'` ---->

```
count 183343.000  
mean 23.656 
std 2010.844 
min 0.000 
25% 0.606 
50% 1.170 
75% 2.251 
max 243441.000
```

I used `df['Col3'].describe()` to get these stats.

Apart from this, I want two more columns `min` and `max` for each bin in the `Bins` column it is nothing but the minimum bin range and maximum bin range for that bin.

---

### **Next step**

The same column from the second data frame i.e. df2 will be processed in a similar way however, instead of creating dynamic bins for the second data frame, I need to map values according to `min` and `max` range of dynamic bins. E.g. For the second dataframe, bin 20 will contain NOBS according to `min` and `max` range of bin 20 from the first data frame. The total number of 'Bins' should be the same i.e. if `dataframe_1` has `Bins` column ranging from `-20` to `66` then `dataframe_2` should have the same number of bins as `dataframe_1` i.e.